# minimum of this function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Define $f(x,y)  =  (a - bx - by)e^{-(x^2+c y^2)}$, where $c > 1$ and $b>a$ then define

$g(x,y)  =  f(x,y)$ if $x<y$ and $g(x,y)=f(y,x)$ if $x>=y$.

Look at the function $g(x,y)$.

Obviously $g(x,y)$ is symmetric about $x=y$ and not differentiable at $x=y$, but I don't know why the minimum of $g(x,y)$ also occurs at $x=y$?

Comment: I think you need some assumptions on the domain of $f$. For example if negative $x,y$ are allowed, the factor $e^{-(x^2+cy^2)}$ might either increase or decrease as $y$ moves away from $x$ on its right.

Comment: @coffeemath: Yep, but actually we don't need to assume the domain. If you use some software to draw the image of $g(x)$, say around $[1,1]\times [1,1]$, you'll find its minimum appears at $x=y$

Comment: As long as you have the software: What happens on the larger domain $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$? Just curious...

Comment: I think I'd want a larger domain than that, and lots of values for the parameters.

Comment: @Graham Hesketh: From regional plotting graph (like $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$), it's the minimum always on $x=y$ by Matlab...

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: In your choice, the graph is just like a plane, not even like a curved surface... You need a larger range. And the result is like what I've said...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume: $$a,b,c,x,y\in\mathbb{R}:\,c>1,$$
and define:
$$g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$$

***Change of coordinates***

Consider: $$x=\frac{1}{2}(v+u),\,\,y=\frac{1}{2}(u-v),$$ $$u=x+y,\,\,v=x-y,$$ $$\displaystyle g(u,v)=\left( a-bu \right) \,{\mathbb{exp}\left[{-\frac{1}{4}\, \left( {v}^{2}+{u}^{2} \right) 
 \left( 1+c \right) +\frac{1}{2}\, \left( 1-c \right)\, u \left| v \right| }\right]}.
$$
The absolute value of $v$ takes care of the piecewise definition, highlights the symmetry and shows that the function is not differentiable w.r.t $v$ at $v=0$.

***Are there stationary values along $v\ne0$?***

$${\frac {\partial }{\partial v}}g \left( u,v\neq 0 \right) =0\Rightarrow \left| v \right| ={\frac { \left( 1-c \right) u}{1+c}}$$

For $c>1\, (c<1)$ there are stationary points along $v$, symmetrically distributed about $v=0$, when $u<0\, (u>0)$; that is the only region in which the above equation is solvable. These stationary points coalesce as $u\rightarrow 0$. Where the above equation is not solvable there can be no stationary points at $v\ne0$ and thus the maximum or minimum of $g$ must lie at the discontinuity $v=0$.

***Are the stationary points at $v\ne0$ maxima or minima?***

For $c>0$ the exponential decays monotonically to zero for large $v$, this, the quadratic nature of the $v$ dependence and the positivity of the exponential term, insure that, where the stationary points exist:

- the value of $g$ at the discontinuity $v=0$, is closer to $0$ than the value of $g$  at the stationary points,
- the stationary points are maxima along $v$ when $a-bu>0$ and are minima when $a-bu<0$.

***When are the conditions for stationary points existing at $v\ne0$ and a negative pre-factor simultaneously solvable?***

Define the prefactor: $$p=a-ub=|b|\left(\mathbb{sign}(a)\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|-\mathbb{sign}(b)u\right)$$

and examine the table below.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline \mathbb{sign}(a)& \mathbb{sign}(b) & \text{cond. on } u\,\, \text{for}\,\, p<0 & \text{min/max} \\ \hline+&+&u>\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|&\text{1 min @}\,v=0,\text{2 max @}\,v\ne0\, \\ \hline +&-&u<-\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|&\text{2 min @}\,v\ne0,\text{1 max @}\,v=0\, \\ \hline -&+&u>-\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|&\text{1 min @}\,v=0,\text{2 max @}\,v\ne0\,  \\ \hline -&-&u<\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|&\text{2 min @}\,v\ne0,\text{1 max @}\,v=0\,\\ \hline \end{array}

For $p<0$ the first two rows force $u$ to be exclusively $+$ or $-$ and the final column is filled in accordingly from previous discussions. In the second two rows $u$ is not required to be exclusively $+$ or $-$ but these are filled in by recognising them as simple over all sign changes in $g$ for rows $1$ and $2$. In the final row, we see that $a<b$ is not sufficient for one minimum at $v=0$ if $b<0$.

Rather, a necessary and sufficient condition
for a single minimum at $v=0$ is: $$0<b,$$
and you then have two maxima at $v\ne0$.

***Where are the stationary points located?***

The min/max stationary point @ $v=0$ is found using:
$${\frac {\partial }{\partial u}}g \left( u,0 \right) ={u}^{2}-{\frac {a
u}{b}}-\, \frac{2}{1+c}
=0,$$ $$u=\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {a}{b}}\pm\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{b}^{2}}}+
 \frac{8}{1+c}},$$

and the conditions in the table dictate that, as $0<c$ (in fact $c>1$), we must chose the $+$ in all cases and thus, in all cases this stationary point is located at:
$$u=\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {a}{b}}+\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{b}^{2}}}+
 \frac{8}{1+c}},\,v=0\,:\,x=y=\frac{1}{4}\,{\frac {a}{b}}+\frac{1}{4}\,\sqrt {{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{b}^{2}}}+
 \frac{8}{1+c}}.$$
In the above, the $-$ choice corresponds to a saddle-like point between the two min/max stationary points @ $v\ne0$. The min/max stationary points @ $v\ne0$ themselves can be located using:
$$\left({\frac {\partial }{\partial u}}g \left( u,v \right)\right)|_{ 
 \left| v \right| ={\frac { ( 1-c ) u}{1+c}}} =0\Rightarrow {u}^{2}-{\frac {a}{b}}u-\frac{1}{2c}-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$u={\frac {a}{2b}}\pm\frac {1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{b}^{2}}}+\frac {2}{c}
+2}$$
and because the existence of these points requires $u<0$ we take the $-$ and we then have the location of two stationary points at:
$$u={\frac {a}{2b}}-\frac {1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{b}^{2}}}+\frac {2}{c}
+2},\,\,v=\pm\frac{1-c}{1+c}\left({\frac {a}{2b}}-\frac {1}{2}\,\sqrt {{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{b}^{2}}}+\frac {2}{c}
+2}\right)$$

**Example:**
$$a=1,b=2,c=3,$$
minimum of $g$ at: $$u=1,v=0:x=y=\frac{1}{2}.$$
[image][image]

Comment: At the point where you argue that $a-bu<0$, since $u=x+y$, it seems your use of $u>1$ to get the negativity of $a-bu$ is an assumption about the domain of $f$, i.e. that $x+y>1$. (I haven't been able to determine what domain is intended by the OP Ian.)

Comment: My opinion of the problem is that one needs either: * positive $x,y$ and more restrictions on $a,b,c$ than the OP's $c>1,b>a$ to force the min to occur on $y=x$, or else * again positive $x,y$ but some other restriction(s) on $x,y$ (perhaps in terms of $a,b,c$) to force the min on $y=x$.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: I have some questions and I think you can add answers of these questions to your answer. (1) What about $u<0$, I know it must be a maximum then but how you prove the situation for $u<0$? (2) Can you prove that in order to have the minimum of $g$ occurs at $x=y$, does it  matter for $a>b$ or $a=b$? (3) What's the role of $c$? What will be affected by changing $c$? These can make the answer more complete. I've tried plotting some of these situations but lack of proofs and  can't make sure of my results...Thank you!

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: I have another question. Though it's obvious that $g(x)$ is not differentiable along $x=y$ (which can be seen from the plot), but how you prove it?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: It seems you haven't responded to (2) and (3)...

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: Well, I care about the actual absolute minimum of the function and so please take the domain as the entire x−y plane...then what about (2) and (3)?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: Is the role of $c$ just deciding stationary points along $v$, which are symmetrically distributed about $v=0$? Does it have a function in deciding the minimum?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: In the last row of the table, can you explain why there are two min @ $v\neq 0$? If $u\geq 0$, there seems only one min when $u=0$ at $v=0$.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: For the table, are you assuming $c>1$? And why not consider condition on $u$ for $p>0$? Is that we'll reach the same results for $p>0$?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: But, for example, the first row, why there are 2 max @ $v\neq 0$?

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: There are no stationary points for the first row where $u>0$, so how do you know there are two max @ $v\neq 0$? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, how are you recently? I still have the problem...Can you tell me, clearly, that why for the first row of the table, there are 2 max @ $v≠0$? You've said in the answer that the stationary points are minima when $a-bu<0$, that is $p<0$. But in the table we always have $p<0$, but why there are 2 max @ $v≠0$ in the first row, not min?

Comment: Hey I have a question for you. See chat.

Comment: Two more questions: 1) for the table, the second row, for example, u can be both <0 and >0, so is that more exact to discuss the min/mix for two cases? 2)Are you talking about everything with the precondition p<0 in the section "Where are the stationary points located"?

Comment: Hey, did you see my question?

Comment: @Ian, $u$ is considered over the entire domain in every row, the constants $a,b$ determine the local sign of $p$, i.e. in that $u$ region, which in turn determines if the stationary points in that region are pointing up or down and thus if they are min or max. The location of the stationary points does not suppose $p<0$. Their location is independent of that condition it is only their classification that is concerned with that, hence the min/max notation.

Answer (score 1):

(not a complete answer, but a start.)

The partial of $f(x,x+t)$ with respect to $t$ at $t=0$ is
$$(4bcx^2-2acx-b)e^{(-c-1)x^2}.$$ 
The quadratic factor here has positive discriminant, so to know for sure one has a max or a min along $y=x$ some assumption about $a,b,c$ must force a certain sign for the quadratic factor. At present I don't see how your conditions $c>1,b>a$ alone decide the sign on the quadratic.